# independent random variables geometric distributon

Tags: probability

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables with the same geometric distribution, $\mathbb{P}(X=k)=\mathbb{P}(Y=k)=pq^{k-1}$ for $k\geq 1$, $q=1-p$.

Find $\mathbb{P}(X=k \mid X+Y=n+1)$, where $n$ is an element of $\left\{1,2,\dots\right\}$. What is this distribution?

Comment: That should be $k \ge 1$, not $k > 1$.

Comment: What did you try? (Removed irrelevant tag.)

Comment: Hint: $P(A\mid B) = \frac{P(AB)}{P(B)}$. What is $P(AB)$ for _your_ particular events $A$ and $B$, and can you express $P(AB)$ in terms of what the value of $X$ must be and what the value of $Y$ must  in order for event $AB$ to occur?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Consider repeatedly tossing a coin with probability $p$ of "heads" on each toss, independently.  $X$ is the number of tosses until the first "heads" and $Y$ the number of tosses after that until the second "heads".  So $X+Y=n+1$ says the second "heads" is on toss number $n+1$.  Given that, the first "heads" could be on any of the first $n$ tosses...

Comment: im sorry for commenting here, im having quite similar problem, to like  this question. may i ask, why when computing $P(X+Y=n+1) = \sum_{i=1}^n \Pr(X=i)\Pr(Y=n+1-i)$? and suppose X is for trial before first head, and Y is trial after first head, and Z is trial when two heads appear, so Z=X+Y, what is we computer join distribution of X and Z? and how can i compute distribution of Z?

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are independent and take positive integer values, condition on the value of $X$.

Comment: thankyou, but $P(X,Y)$ means probability Y (head 2 times appear) and X (head first time appear)? while $P(X+Y)$ means probability Y (head 2 times appear) given that X (head first time appear)?

Comment: No, that all makes no sense.  $X$ and $Y$ are random variables.  $P(X)$ or $P(X,Y)$ or $P(X+Y)$  don't mean anything  $P(X=x)$ means the probability that $X=x$ (i.e. $X$ takes the value $x$).  $P(X=x, Y=y)$ is the probability that $X=x$ and $Y=y$.  $P(X+Y=z)$ is the probability that the value of $X$ and the value of $Y$  sum to $z$.

Comment: ok thankyou! but im still confuse with the conditioning part in the $P(X=x, Y=y)$ ,$P(X+Y=z)$ means probability second heads is on toss number Z given that first toss is in X or it just means P(Z) which is Z is sum of X and Y? can i say $P(X+Y=z)$=$P(X=x).P(Z=z|X=x)$? or  $P(X=x).P(Y=y|X=x)$?,

Comment: $P(Z=z) = \sum_x P(X=x) P(Z=z|X=x)$ where $\Sigma_x$ means the sum over all possible values $x$ of $X$.  Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $P(Z=z|X=x) = P(Y=z-x)$.

Comment: thankyou it clear my confusion. but when you say that $P(Z=z|X=x) = P(Y=z-x)$ , Z=X+Y , this means, $\frac{P(X=x)P(Y=y=Z-x)}{P(X=x)}$? its actually Z means X and Y? so its same as $Z=P(X=x)P(Y=y=Z-x)$?

Answer (score 2):

If the answer is not intuitively obvious, we can always **calculate**. We want $\Pr(X=k|X+Y=n+1)$. By the usual expression for conditional probabilities, we have
$$\Pr(X=k|X+Y=n+1)=\frac{\Pr((X=k) \cap (X+Y=n+1))}{\Pr(X+Y=n+1)}.$$

Calculate. The probability on top is the probability that $X=k$ and $Y=n+1-k$. This is $q^{k-1}p q^{n-k}p$, which simplifies to $p^2 q^{n-1}$.

The probability at the bottom is $\sum_{i=1}^n \Pr(X=i)\Pr(Y=n+1-i)$. This is
$$\sum_{i=1}^n q^{i-1}p q^{n-i}p,$$
which is $np^2 q^{n-1}$.

Divide. We get $\dfrac{1}{n}$.