# Question about random variables with Geometric Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I was doing the next excercise:

> Let $X$ and $Y$ independent random variables with geometric distribution and same parameter $p$. Find $P\left( X=k\vert X+Y=n\right)$.

This is what I did

$P\left(X=k\vert X+Y=n\right)=\frac{P\left(X=k, X+Y=n\right)}{P\left(X+Y=n\right)}=\frac{P\left(X=k, Y=n-X\right)}{P\left(Y=n-X\right)}=\frac{P\left(X=k\right)P\left( Y=n-X\right)}{P\left(Y=n-X\right)}=P(X=k)$

My question is, can i asume the independence of $X$ and $Y$ when I express $Y=n-X$?

Comment: Can you explain why $ P ( X = k, Y = n - X) = P ( X = k) P ( Y = n - X)$?. In particular, note that $ n - X$ is not a constant.

Comment: $\mathsf P(X=k, Y=n-X)=\mathsf P(X=k, Y=n-k)$ and $\mathsf P(Y=n-k\mid X=k) = \mathsf P(Y=n-k)$...  However, $\mathsf P(Y=n-X)\neq \mathsf P(Y=n-k)$ .

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/306462/independent-random-variables-geometric-distributon?rq=1  seems to be same question.

Comment: Yes now i see my mistake, I'm having some trouble with the definitions, sorry for answering this late I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3):

Let $q=1-p$,
\begin{align}
P(X=k | X+Y=n)&= \frac{P(X=k, Y=n-k)}{P(X+Y=n)} \\
&= \frac{P(X=k) P(Y=n-k)}{\sum_{l=1}^{n-1}P(X=l)P(Y=n-l)} \\
&=\frac{q^{k-1}pq^{n-k-1}p}{\sum_{l=1}^{n-1}q^{l-1}pq^{n-l-1}p}\\
&=\frac{q^{n-2}}{\sum_{l=1}^{n-1}q^{n-2}}\\
&= \frac{1}{n-1}
\end{align}

Comment: Error in calculation: $q^{k-1}q^{n-k-1}=q^{n-2}$ not $=q^{n-2k-2}$.  Final answer is then $\frac{1}{\sum\limits_{l=1}^{n-1}q^{-2l}}$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the mistake.

Comment: Note: similar error in denominator.

Answer (score 1):

As stated, the event can occur only when $X=k$ and $Y=n-k$ so the probability you want is $A=P(X=k)P(Y=n-k)/P(X+Y=n)$.
Let $x_k=P(X=k)$ and $y_k=P(Y=k)$ Then $A=\frac{x_ky_{n-k}}{\sum\limits_{j=j_0}^{n_0} x_jy_{n-j}}$.
For geometric distribution $x_jy_{n-j}$ depends only on $n$.

Wikipedia has two similar distributions called geometric. In one definition (a) $a_k$ means $k$ failures before first success $(j_0=0, n_0=n)$, while the other (b) means $k$ is the index of the first success $(j_0=1, n_0=n-1)$, so for (a) $A=\frac{1}{n+1}$ while for (b) $A=\frac{1}{n-1}$.